# How do I drop rows with NaN in any column from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to select and then drop from pandas DataFrame all rows that have a NaN value in any of the columns.

Am aware of how to filter by a single column using a boolean Series: `df.loc[np.isnan(df['col1'])]`, but I can't figure out how to extend this so as to filter from multiple columns.

Basically, I want to get rid of all rows that have a NaN value. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please explain with sample data and your expected output to get a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.dropna()
```

If I got you right, the above code would do the job